# disable moving cards between lists

Tags: trello

I like the way Trello on Trello lists are "locked" to the degree where users cannot move cards between lists (only for board owner/admin).  Is there a setting that controls this feature?

Answer (score 2):

https://trello.com/dev is not locked in any way. All members of a board can move cards between lists. The public can vote and comment.

You can make something similar by allowing your organization to vote and comment, but only making the people who will be arranging cards on the board actual members.

Comment: Thanks Rich.  I understand it is not a setting but if I make the board public, then is it available to the general public?  I don't really want that, I prefer a subset of the public which I believe you are referring to the "organization".  Could you please let me know if/how this subset is identified?

Comment: @KellyGutowski You can create organizations here https://trello.com/org/create. There's more information about orgs in the guide https://trello.com/guide